# I want to be able to get ergast (historical record of motor racing data for non-commercial purposes) data into PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way to get [Ergast](http://ergast.com/mrd/) data into PostgreSQL. I have thought of writing some code to pull down the data from the API but there are SQL dumps for [MySQL and ANSI](http://ergast.com/mrd/db/) but neither run on PostgreSQL.

I would prefer not to import into MySQL to export into CSV... Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing with this for a presentation I may do and have a quick hacky solution using some basic UNIX tools... It's pretty hacky but does work.

```
cat  f1db_ansi.sql | sed 's/int(..)/int/' | sed 's/ \+AUTO_INCREMENT//' |  sed "s/\\\'/\'\'/g" |  sed 's/UNIQUE KEY \"\(\w\+\)\"/UNIQUE /' | sed 's/^ *KEY .*(\"\(.*\)\")/CHECK ("\1" > 0)/' | sed 's/ date NOT NULL DEFAULT .0000.*,/ date,/'| psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d f1 -q -b
```

Where f1db_ansi.sql is the ANSI SQL data dump from the site.

This is correct as of 25th July 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this guide how use pgloader from mysql: https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/blob/master/docs/tutorial/mysql.rst

Comment: This is good, probably better if you're in a place where you can install MySQL